# Question on Spearman r interpretation

Tags: correlation, spearman-rho

Given two random variables $X = \{x_1,...,x_n\}$ and $Y = \{y_1,...,y_n\}$.

Does the following hold true?

$Spearmanr(X,Y) < 1 \iff \exists i,j$, s.t. $(x_i - x_j)\cdot(y_i-y_j) < 0$.

I have the feeling that it should, but I am not certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right side means that the ranking of $x_i, x_j$ is the reverse of $y_i, y_j$. 
If this happens, Spearman's $r$ cannot be one. Correct. On the other hand, if no such thing exists, rankings in $x$ and $y$ must be the same and Spearman's $r$ must be 1 *if all values in $X$, $Y$ are different*. Otherwise, chances are that cases can be constructed in which you only find $(x_i-x_j)(y_i-y_j)=0$ for which Spearman's $r$ is not 1 (I'm not even sure whether Spearman is uniquely defined in that case).